# Copy Files and Metadata in AIX/Linux

Tags: linux, file, aix

I have to Copy/Move 80 Folders with 5000 files in them + metadata and I can't figure out the best way to do because I am a windows guy.  Can someone help?

Comment: Well, in Windows you would use some Commander, wouldn't you? In unix, there is Midnight Commander [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Commander]

Comment: Try testing with smaller folders and `cp -r orgdir targetdir`.

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific, i.e. from one server location to another or between servers or operating systems.

Generally speaking, I would recommend rsync.  Rsync can 1) just copy the deltas 2) be run in archive mode to preserve ownership and permissions 3) can use ssh for security and convenience using keys 4) can be run in dry-run mode to test and 5) is available for multiple platforms, including windows (cygwin).